# Putting data into array then show it in a table

Tags: php

So i have 0 experience with array's and putting them into a table. I tried google but there are no good results

Currently my script is this

```
<?php
$cats = explode("|", $_POST['cat_name']);
echo $cats[0]; // cat_id
?>
<?php

$url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category='.$cats[0].'&alpha=a&page=1';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonArray = json_decode($result);
print_r($jsonArray);
?>
```

with this as a result:

> 1{"total":5,"items":[{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=4798","id":4798,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant
>   brutal","description":"Blunt adamantite
>   arrow...ouch","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":222},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=810","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=810","id":810,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant
>   dart","description":"A deadly throwing dart with an adamant
>   tip.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":11},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=829","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=829","id":829,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant
>   javelin","description":"An adamant tipped
>   javelin.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":64},"today":{"trend":"positive","price":"+1"}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=867","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=867","id":867,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant
>   knife","description":"A finely balanced throwing
>   knife.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":23},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=804","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=804","id":804,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant
>   throwing axe","description":"A finely balanced throwing
>   axe.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":180},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}}]}

So my question is : How do i put this into a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
foreach($jsonArray["items"] as $item) {
    echo "<tr>
          <td>" . $item["id"] . "</td><td> 
          <td>" . htmlspecialchars($item["type"]) . "</td><td>
          <td>" . htmlspecialchars($item["name"]) . "</td><td>
          <td><img src='" . $item["icon"] . "'></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in `  `on line `foreach($jsonArray["items"] as $item) {`

Comment: try: `$jsonArray->items` instead